# In Lightroom, how can I automatically apply profile corrections on import?

Tags: lightroom-4

I almost always want the profile correct applied, but it's an extra step. Any ideas on how to apply these automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure a photo with the adjustments you want and then go to Develop, Set Default Settings.  You can actually specify per camera or even per ISO settings if you want by altering the settings under Edit, Preferences, Presets.

Comment: Works great. I just have to remember **not** to do this when I'm using a fisheye lens as the profile corrections will make images rectilinear.

Answer (score 0):

What AJ said is correct.Another option is that you can create a user preset with any set of corrections you want, not just the profile correction, and then you can set the import routine to apply it on all imported images. I do this because there are a certain set of modifications I do to all of my images -- a basic sharpening, a bit of saturation reduction in the yellow channel (Canon sensors put too much yellow in foliage, IMHO), a bit of boost to the blue, a bit of clarity. By defining these as a user preset, I don't have to. Adn if I have a special set of images that I don't think they're appropriate for? I can turn it off for that import.

I also keep another user preset called "Zero", which sets everything back to the original values (well, "my" original values, not Lightroom's). that way, if I have some images where the import preset didn't work well, I can easily turn it off for those images. Or ig I screw up processing, not that I ever do.